# App build succeeds with Pyinstaller version 4.3 but not 4.4 due to AttributeError: Module 'PyQt5' has no attribute '__version__'

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller

I'm using Python 3.9.5 and wanted to upgrade my Pyinstaller to the most recent version since I was encountering problems getting my app notarized. Everything worked fine with version 4.3, but building with 4.4 failed and resulted in a lengthy message ending with

`AttributeError: Module 'PyQt5' has no attribute '__version__'`

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it on my system by following:

`pip install PyQt5 --user --use-feature=2020-resolver`

`pip install pyqtwebengine jedi  parso pyqt5`

(If asked / not present on your system)

Ref: [CSDN.net blog](https://blog.csdn.net/qq_41685265/article/details/119717851)